# Overloading a route one and two variables in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I recently upgraded from rails 3 to rails 4 on one of our legacy apps, the problem is that rails 4 doesn't allow the same path name on two URLs even if they take a different number of arguments.

E.g. we used to do this:

```
  get "object/:id/data/:dataid" => "object#data", as: :object_data
  get "object/:id/data/:dataid/:extra" => "object#data", as: :object_data
```

but in rails 4 having two `object_data_paths` is not allowed. I'm wanting to accomplish the same thing as before. It seems like one method would be to call the second one something new, but use the same method, i.e.:

`get "object/:id/data/:dataid/:extra" => "object#data", as: :object_data_extra`

But this does seem like a worse solution than before. Any other ways I can do this? Thoughts on why we have to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions. The first is to use an optional path segment:

```
get "object/:id/data/:dataid(/:extra)" => "object#data", as: :object_data
```

The other is to wrap it in a helper:

```
get "object/:id/data/:dataid"        => "object#data", as: :object_data_1
get "object/:id/data/:dataid/:extra" => "object#data", as: :object_data_2

# And in application_helpers.rb or somewhere similar

def object_data_path(id, dataid, extra=nil)
  if extra
    object_data_2_path(id, dataid, extra)
  else
    object_data_1_path(id, dataid)
  end
end
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank for letting me know both solutions.